# CSS{ Invalid property value for content: url( )

Tags: php, css

[FILE inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3q9Jr.png)

As you can see, I get an invalid property value error.
If the code is done right, there should be options with the image urls displayed in the picture.
There is an additional css for radio span in the php below and I am using bootstrap 5.1 css

here is my product_view.php

```
<style>
    .col{
        border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
    }

    [type=radio] {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
    }

    [type=radio] + span {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    [type=radio]:checked + span {
        outline: 5px solid indigo;
    }
</style>

<section class="signin-page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <div class="block text-center" style="background-color:#FFFFF0;">
         <div class="signinlogo">
         <div class="logo text-center">
                <a href="../../index.php"><tspan x="70.94" y="325">Sutra Craft</tspan></a>
            </div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="text-align:center;">
      <img id="pimg" src="<?php echo $rs->thumbnail;?>" style="max-width:200px;">
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <h3><?php echo $rs->name;?></h3>
        <div>
          가격 : <span id="price"><?php echo number_format($rs->price);?></span>원
        </div>
        <?php if($options1){?>
        <br>
         <!-- <div>
            옵션 :
            <select name="poption" id="poption">
                <option value="">선택하세요</option>
                <?php foreach($options as $op){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $op->poid;?>"><?php echo $op->option_name;?></option>
                <?php }?>
            </select>
        </div> -->
        <br>
        <div>
        <?php 
        
        foreach($options1 as $op1){?>
                <input type="radio" name="poption1" id="poption1_<?php echo $op1->poid;?>" value="<?php echo $op1->poid;?>">
                    <span  onclick="jQuery('#poption1_<?php echo $op1->poid;?>').click();" style="content:url(<?php echo $op1->image_url;?>);height:100px;width:100px;"></span>
                </input>
            <?php }?>
           
        </div>
        <br>
        <div>
```

I tried changing the css property from content: url() to background: url()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the URL in quotes like

```
content: url('link-to-file.jpg');
```

You are facing this issue because the URL has a space in it.

Comment: I did wrap the url, check the php file --> style="content:url(<?php echo $op1->image_url;?>)

Comment: Please wrap only the url part as well `style="content: url('<?php echo $op1->image_url;?>')"`. Please note the single quotes

Comment: Thank you FatalError, you solved it (thumbs up)

Comment: @JinSingh Please mark the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: what is marking?